# How do I disable trusted browsers check in facebook?

Tags: security, login, facebook

Recently, I enabled the trusted browsers feature, but now I want to disable it. I went to disable the feature and it doesn't appear to give me that option. How do I turn this feature off, so I won't be asked to confirm every time I log in from a strange browser? I disabled the option of receiving e-mails from Facebook about it all the time, which are very annoying and a waste of my time.

I saw this page but it didn't help:
https://www.facebook.com/help/339635806085622

Comment: I don't see any difference between configuration in a software on my pc and a software on the web. But u r right to block this as it is off topic according to the help center. Can you please change the down vote? Feel free to delete the question if you want.

Comment: They are differently scoped, in the sense that not only we would have to consider the web interface, but whatever browser it was run. A simple search regarding the topic showed the following [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/339635806085622) help page, which seems that you can just alter your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings->Security and turn off "Login Notifications" ([direct link](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=notifications&view)). This will disable the email you get when you log on from an unknown browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I disabled the email notification as I mentioned in my question

Comment: I added the email notification and than disabled it gain and it seemed to solve the problem. Thanks